# If I have a very small n for one group and a very large number of features, should I choose a parametric or a non-parametric test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, nonparametric, parametric

I have a dataset that contains human metabolite concetration in a fluid. One group has about 12 samples, while another only has 5. My question is if I can assume normality for this data and do ANOVA/t-tests or if, given the small data-set and large number of features, I should do non-parametric tests.

So, for example, one of the features looks like this for the control group:

[image: Q-Q plot]

I mean, it follows a normal distribution maybe, but with so few points, can I really say it does? Also, should each feature follow a normal distribution for the 2 groups individually?

Then there's features that look like this:

[image: Q-Q plot that looks bimodal if 5 points can be bimodal]

Now if I plot their densities I get stuff like this, note that the data is log2 transformed:

[image]

Comment: are these two groups : experimental and control group?

Comment: @Subhash C. Davar yes they are, the smallest is the control group for some bizarre reason.

Comment: Can you add a plot of your data?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the raw data, rather than a QQ plot.

Comment: oh, like a scatter plot? or a density plot?

Comment: How do you compute metabolite concentration - as Ratio or percentage or as a number?

Comment: as a number (micromolar concentrations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if the assumptions are met, parametric tests are more powerful than their non-parametric equivalents.

But the problem here is not parametric vs. non-parametric, it's sample size and power and maybe overfitting.

Suppose you have only one feature to test. Then the difference would have to be huge to be statistically significant, and the parameter estimate will be very imprecisely measured. The exact numbers you will get depend on the exact situation, but let's say the groups have means that are 2 SD apart.

```
set.seed(1234) #Sets a seed

x <- rnorm(12, 10, 1)
y <- rnorm(5, 12, 1)
```

The result is statistically significant, but the 95% CI for the difference is -3.2 to -1.5, which isn't very good.

```
Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x and y
t = -5.94, df = 10.461, p-value = 0.0001193
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -3.250345 -1.484742
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 9.557737 11.925281
```

And, if you start to get into more complex models, you run the risk of overfitting (even if the model is just a little more complex).

Comment: But how can I know if the assumptions are met when the sample size is so small?

Comment: It can be tricky, for sure. One more problem with small samples.

Comment: could i try fitting an ANOVA for each feature and then doing qq plots on the residuals? because I don't think I could do a single ANOVA on like 50 features for the sample size I have, right? I say ANOVA because I could add factors like age and sex.

Comment: Yes, you could try that.  And no, you can't include 50 features. With so little data, I'd say one feature.  But if you are trying 50 features, you then might need to consider multiple comparisons. There is an old book "Statistical Strategies for Small Sample Research" that might be useful to you.

Comment: Thank you! If I instead selected features based on a supervised clustering method, could I use ANOVA on only the features that have like VIP > 1, or am I introducing some sort of bias. Sorry for asking so many questions

Comment: I have no idea.

Comment: When the sample size is too small to study one feature it is way too small to study more than one feature.  And why would one ever think of us a parametric test in this situation when the data are incapable to telling you anything useful about the distributional and variance assumptions?

Comment: @FrankHarrell yeah, my logic is that in theory human metabolite concentrations should be normally distributed right? We would expect that, especially for healthy controls. But then you're saying I shouldn't over-complicate things and just go with a non-parametric test?

Comment: Why would metabolite concentrations have a normal distribution?  What biomathematics dictates that?  Nonparametric methods are very efficient even if normality were to miraculously hold.

Comment: Oh okay, so I should go with non-parametric for all metabolites even if a couple so seem to be normally distributed?

Comment: @FrankHarrell but aren't mesures like height supposed to be normally distributed? Shouldn't metabolite concentrations also be?

Comment: Why do you think anything should be Gaussian?  It is true that heights tend to be **more** normally distributed than most variables, but normality of raw measurements in pretty much an accident of nature.  The shape of the distribution also depends on study enrollment criteria.

Comment: Ok, so I care about the normality of the measurements I have, not whether or not the variable is normally distributed in a population? And I mean not perfectly Gaussian, but to the degree that a test might handle some deviation? I'm pretty new to statistics. The main reason why I want to do a parametric test is because my boss insisted on doing a 2-way ANOVA on some metabolites he felt needed to be significant.